# shell scripting echo not working inside sudo

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I have a shell script `test.sh` as give below.

```
sudo -H sh -c '
    echo $1;    
'
```

But while I am running this script as `./test.sh abcd` it is not echoing anything. Then I changed my script as given below.

```
sudo -H sh -c '
    echo \$1;    
'
```

But now, it is displaying output as `$1`. What modification shall I need to do here for getting output as `abcd`. Please advice as I am a very beginner in shell scripting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo -H sh -c '
echo "$1";    
' argv0 "$1"
```

From the `bash` man page:

```
man bash | less -Ip '-c string'

# -c string If the -c option is present,  then  commands  are  read  from
# string.   If  there  are arguments after the string, they are
# assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo -H sh -c "
  echo $1;    
"
```

`sudo` runs the command in a new shell that doesn't know anything about the argument(s) passed to its parent, so you need to expand them before running the command string in the new (sub)shell.